# Any way I can spoof the value of System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory?

Tags: directory, dns, active-directory, windows-10, directoryservices

I've got some non-domain machines which need to run a piece of software.
The software won't run as it checks the domain the machine is in looking for a specific value and throws an exception and crashes because the machines arent in the domain it's looking for.

Is there any way I can spoof this domain value at all?

Joining the domain isn't an option, so I need a workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what the software is doing, it's impossible to answer this. For example, if it is checking if the computer is joined to a domain, then the only way to get around that is to join the computer to a domain.

Comment: Maybe ask whoever wrote the software. Or use a VM that is joined to a domain.

Comment: I've approached the software vendor for a solution, but I'm going to be waiting a long time before I get a solution from them.

Comment: I can't domain join the machines as its Microsoft's new MMD technology, they're controlled by MDM and Intune and its Managed desktop, so domain join isnt an option. It would be ideal if i can essentially set that value within the windows environment so that when the dll makes the call to see if its on a domain, it reports back whatever value i provide and carries on. Any suggestions appriciated :)

Comment: The problem is, it depends on *how* it determines if it's on a domain. It could be just looking if the *user* is logged in with a domain account by checking the `USERDOMAIN` environment variable. Or it could be looking in the registry. If you're willing to put in the effort, you could use something like [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to watch what it's doing and try to figure where it's looking for the information. But that will be a lot of data to look through.